# What does the 'n' stand for in the UEFI/EFI shell script file extension?

Tags: uefi, efi, file-extension

(U)EFI shells support the [execution of scripts](https://web.archive.org/web/20130615191954/http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/efi-shells-and-scripting) much like a typical *nix shell does. These scripts have the extension `.nsh`. Out of purely esoteric curiosity: what does the '**n**' stand for? I feel it's safe to assume that '**sh**' is the usual "shell", but I can't think of what the 'n' would stand for, and I have not managed to find it myself after crawling about Google and old EFI references.

Comment: maybe *no shell*?

Comment: It's probably to differentiate from actual *NIX shell scripts, which use the `.sh` file extension by convention.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn That's a good point, but they could have chosen just about anything to achieve that, so why 'n'?

Comment: I'm not sure why 'n' specifically, though I can say with near certainty why they didn't choose 'c', 'k' or 'z' (all three would name other existing *NIX shells (csh, ksh, and ZSH)).  'p' probably got excluded for a similar reason (PowerShell, even though it uses `.ps1` as an extension).  `.esh` and `.ush` appear to both be taken (respectively 'extended shell batch' files for DOS and files for something called 'Creative SIMPL Windows' according to a Google search), so they're also out.  Beyond that, I'm not sure.

Comment: Stupid I know but I always assumed it stood for "new shell"